# Tensorflow in Docker on MacOs cannot load libraries with the tensorflow/tensorflow:latest image

Tags: macos, docker, tensorflow

Following the Getting Started guide for running Tensorflow in a docker container yields an error very quickly. Working through the instructions [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/docker), I pulled the `tensorflow/tensorflow:latest` image and then tried running:

```
docker run -it --rm tensorflow/tensorflow:latest python -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random.normal([1000, 1000])))"
```

It's billed as a cpu-only image (under section https://www.tensorflow.org/install/docker#examples_using_cpu-only_images), which I believe I need because I'm running on a Mac, and don't have an Nvidia graphics card. However, the following errors occur:

```
~/> docker run -it --rm tensorflow/tensorflow:latest python -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random.normal([1000, 1000])))"
2020-01-12 18:53:17.848471: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer.so.6'; dlerror: libnvinfer.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2020-01-12 18:53:17.848763: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer_plugin.so.6'; dlerror: libnvinfer_plugin.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2020-01-12 18:53:17.848843: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:30] Cannot dlopen some TensorRT libraries. If you would like to use Nvidia GPU with TensorRT, please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly.
2020-01-12 18:53:18.288367: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'libcuda.so.1'; dlerror: libcuda.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2020-01-12 18:53:18.288461: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:351] failed call to cuInit: UNKNOWN ERROR (303)
2020-01-12 18:53:18.288516: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:156] kernel driver does not appear to be running on this host (996a2dd2ab59): /proc/driver/nvidia/version does not exist
2020-01-12 18:53:18.289117: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2020-01-12 18:53:18.295734: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:94] CPU Frequency: 2592000000 Hz
2020-01-12 18:53:18.296844: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x55c37f5f81f0 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-01-12 18:53:18.296881: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
tf.Tensor(-203.31216, shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

Are the instructions misleading (saying latest is a cpu-only image) or am I missing something? I see references to cuda in the output so it would seem this isn't a cpu-only image? Should I be using a different image?

Here are my specs:

```
macOs Mojave - 10.14.6
Docker Desktop - 2.1.0.6
docker - 19.03.5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this same issue not long ago, but I discovered that it actually prints the correct result, and those logs might be warnings.

The result of `print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random.normal([1000, 1000])))` is actually `tf.Tensor(-203.31216, shape=(), dtype=float32)`, which is in the last line of what was printed out.

[image: this is what mine printed out on jupyter notebook]

if you can run your code in a jupyter notebook, then you should use the jupyter/tensorflow-notebook image.

Set it up this way:

1. `docker pull jupyter/tensorflow-notebook`
2. `docker run -p 8888:8888 jupyter/tensorflow-notebook`

After running the container, a link would be displayed on the terminal that you can use to access the notebook. Copy the link and paste in your browser, and start writing your code. It worked well for me without any of those "Warnings" printed out.

If the tensorflow container runs your code correctly with those errors still printed out, please let me know. But for now I am using the jupyter notebook container and I am not getting any errors or warnings.

If i find a way of clearing those warnings, I will let you know here.

Answer (score 0):

I met this problem too, and I was trying to run on a PC. Because the nvidia-docker doesn't support Windows, I also have to use the cpu-only image.

As Odohi David said, you can run your code in a jupyter notebook. You may run it with the official image like this:

```
docker run -it -p 8888:8888 tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-py3-jupyter
```

Then open `localhost:8888` in your browser. You will need a token to access the notebook and you can find it in the terminal. For example:

```
[I 13:57:13.801 NotebookApp] http://8c6f388f31c0:8888/?token=44ec1f209c1777c4c1b28b38b9842f297e170cbacf24b291
```

In this case, the token is `44ec1f209c1777c4c1b28b38b9842f297e170cbacf24b291`.

After that, you can access to the official `tensorflow-tutorials`, and write your code on the notebook.